# bootstrap navbar not aligned properly

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running a site [navrcholu.cz](http://navrcholku.cz/) on latest wordpress and bootstrap. However my navbar is not displayed correctly expecially on tablets. It should be always like 30px from the top of the page. On desktop PC with FF or Chrome looks OK.
Here is navbar code:

```
  <header class="container-fluid header-pic">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar1">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
            <?php if((is_home()) or (is_page()) or (is_search())) : ?>
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <h1 class="h1trans"><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <h2 class="h1trans"><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h2>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar1">
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()));
            ?>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

A header-pic class goes here:

```
 .header-pic {
 background-image: url("pics/img.jpg");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: top left;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 65%;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 margin-top:-20px;
}
```

I make a use of couple media queries, asking for the width and serving smaller or bigger header picture accordingly. I am not overriding a positon property of bootstrap navbar itself.

Like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 385px) and (max-width: 769px)  {
   .header-pic {
    background-image: url("pics/img50.jpg");
    background-position: top left;
    height: 65%;
    }}
```

What I am doing wrong? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Need a working jsfiddle code where we can play with your code and fix it. Just post `navbar` code in jsfiddle and pass the link here. If you want full screen results, then try `JSbin`

Comment: @AjayKulkarni  Here's a link to [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7h182x2/1/).

Comment: `It should be always like 30px from the top of the page`. Please elaborate it

Comment: @AjayKulkarni    The distance or pixels doesnt matter for now. The navbar should be always on the top. I scroll down --> navbar with picture dissapear. Standart behavior I think.

Comment: You want `nav-bar` to be fixed, right?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni   No, I dont want see the navbar all time. So, no fixed. I want it static. I added the class        navbar-static-top to jsfiddle, to see if helps, but it did not.

Comment: `The navbar should be always on the top`:  That's what you told. To do that, you should fix the `navbar` by using `navbar-fixed-top` class

Comment: @AjayKulkarni  This was probably misunderstanding. I want it to be on the top of the **header**, not top of whole page. See how it went away on Nexus7 tablet -  [broken navbar](http://navrcholku.cz/wrong.JPG)

Comment: Okay, check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I'd modify the `CSS` like this:

```
nav
{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
}
```